# input text value

Tags: html, forms, input

ok this is it... i need to submit a form where the user enters a info in a input box but the value has other text aswell.

for example: user - enters **123** value is - www.helloneed**123**help.com submit

the 123 from the url is what the user entered

this is code i have:

```
<form name="postcode" method="post" action="location.html">
<input type="text" name="post" id="post" required="required"  maxlength="8" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

any ideas? sheraz

Comment: ps. the www.helloneed & help.com are fixed meaning they do not change at all

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery needed, straight JavaScript.

Add the following directly after the form HTML:

```
<script>
document.forms.postcode.onsubmit = function(){    
    this.post.value = 'www.helloneed' + this.post.value + 'help.com';
    alert(this.post.value);
}​
</script>
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/ZeKUq/

Comment: Remove the `alert()` once testing is completed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'onclick' event in input tag and write javascript code there.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit" onclick="post.value='www.helloneed' + post.value + 'help.com';" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try prepending & appending text to the value of the inputbox.

e.g. onsubmit="$('#post').val('http://www.helloneed' + $('#post').val() + 'help.com');

This may work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="postcode" method="post" action="location.html" onsubmit="$('#post').val('http://www.helloneed' + $('#post').val() + 'help.com'); return false">
<input type="text" name="post" id="post" required="required"  maxlength="8" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

(After your first test, I would remove the return false text)

Andrew

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to do this in HTML. Such issues should be handled server-side.

It’s easy to do this in JavaScript, as outlined in iambriansreed’s answer, but it’s equally simple and much more robust to do it server-side. In a case like this, there isn’t even any need to do it client-side as well; it would just complicate things, as the server-side code would have no direct way of knowing what it gets (direct user input vs. input modified by client−side JavaScript when enabled).